# Non linear mapping to vector of higher dimension

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, dimensions, pytorch

I am learning Keras and need help on the following. I currently have a sequence of floats in lists X and Y. What I need to do is to have a non-linear mapping to map each element to a vector of higher dimension following the below equation.

```
pos(i) = tanh(W.[concat(X[i],Y[i]])
#where W is a learnable weight matrix, concat performs the concatenation and pos(i) is a vector of 16x1. (I'm trying to create 16 channel inputs for a CNN).
```

I found that Pytorch implementation for the above is

```
m = nn.linear(2,16)
input = torch.cat(X[i],Y[i])    
torch.nn.functional.tanh(m(input))
```

Currently I've tried the concat and tanh in numpy and it seems that is not what I want here.

Can you help me implement the above using Keras.

Comment: well this is essentially a dense layer in keras with tanh activations. you should be able to get around concatenating vector by vector. Mind sharing your model?

Comment: @putonspectacles Thanks for the response, Will the dense layer also provide the vector of higher dimension? input vector after concat looks like this [39.147,105.248]. `model.add(Dense(units=16, input_shape=(1,), activation='tanh', use_bias=True))` What I need is a 16 channel input feature vector that then can be used to convolve with different kernels.

Comment: yes, see my answer for a related example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you have there.

This is what I would do in keras. Im going to assume that you just want your to concatenate your inputs before you feed them into the model.

So we'll do it with numpy. Note

something like :

```
import numpy as np
from keras.model import Dense, Model,Input
X = np.random.rand(100, 1)
Y = np.random.rand(100, 1)
y = np.random.rand(100, 16)
# concatenate along the features in numpy
XY = np.cancatenate(X, Y, axis=1)


# write model
in = Input(shape=(2, ))
out = Dense(16, activation='tanh')(in)
# print(out.shape) (?, 16)
model = Model(in, out)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(XY, y)


....
```

Comment: Great. This model is what I need. In my case X and Y are latitudes and longitudes. latitudes have values of 30... (30.1234, 30.457, 30.12..) and longitudes have values around 104 (104.256, 103.789, 104.2365...). I changed `X = np.random.rand(100, 1)+30
Y = np.random.rand(100, 1)+104` and then the 12 channels are same for all(-1 and 1 in all cases). Could you please help me here. For inputs between 0 and 1 model works perfectly. Thanks for this big help.

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: `model.predict([30.649338,104.095559]) # Produces [1,-1,-0.999,-1,-0.996,-1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-0.999] to almost every geo coordinate provide`. I thought X, Y, y being values between 0 and 1 this may happen. So I changed X and Y as above comment and Still it gives me the same result(only 1s and -1s). If I provide a vector with values between 0 and 1 - `model.predict([[0.2356,0.75236]]) produces [-0.193602,0.109489,0.15506,0.2324,-0.41256,...] and this is the kind of vector I need for my geo coordinates also`.

Comment: open another question with your model and I'll see if I can offer help there.

Comment: thanks for your great support on this matter. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49388199/obtaining-feature-vector-from-geo-coordinates) contains more info on the problem